# Recode/concatenate multiple values python

Tags: python, numpy, recode

I have a df that I wish to perform some recoding on, and I'm not sure what is the best approach.

For values from `1` to `9`, I need to add `5900` to the number (so for `1`, it would be `59001`).
For values from `10` to `99`, I need to add `590` to the number
For values from `100` to `175`, I need to add `59` to the number

Is there a way to automate this process, instead of manually recoding?

I have the following, but it returns an error

```
def recode(df):
    for n, i in enumerate(list(df)):
        for num in range(0,10):
            if i == num: df[n] = int(str(5900) + str(i))

        for num in range(10,100):
            if i == num: df[n] = int(str(590) + str(i))

        for num in range(100,200):
            if i == num: df[n] = int(str(59) + str(i))
    return(list)

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(recode_fips_ohio)
```

Returns error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one line of code:

```py
df += 59000
```